Disable astra_get_search_form from generating in header
I have a website with an Astra child theme.
Astra is generating a search form in my header.
The form is generated 4x by Astra, and as the method="get".
I don't use this form, and there is nothing in the header custom that ask it to be generated...
I am not able to figure out how to stop astra_get_search_form to generate on the header, in a PHP way.
I was able to remove from html, using jquery:
/* REMOVE form get */
    $(".ast-search-box.header-cover").remove();

But I would prefer to remove using php, directly at the source.
Here is the function for the astra_get_search_form: https://developers.wpastra.com/astra-theme/reference/functions/astra_get_search_form/
Thanks in advance for your help.
-- Edit -- I found this article that give how to remove the whole header.

https://wpastra.com/docs/remove-astra-header-from-entire-site/
https://developers.wpastra.com/astra-theme/reference/classes/astra_builder_header/global_astra_header/

But still could not apply it for this search element...

You'll need to check with the theme's support team about this. Third-party theme support is off topic here.

I posted it there too, but I just ask for an extra as it can probably be solved using php skills and wordpress function, based on doc: https://developers.wpastra.com/astra-theme/reference/functions/astra_get_search_form/
